# Postgres query for recursive operation on rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table foo (a int, b float);

insert into foo values (1, 2), (2,3),(3,2.5),(4,1.5);

 a |  b  
---+-----
 1 |   2
 2 |   3
 3 | 2.5
 4 | 1.5
```

I want to calculate the difference of each `b` for any `a`

```
select RECURSIVE diff (?,?) on b where a=1
```

OUTPUT:

```
 a |  diff  
---+-----
 1 |   0
 2 |   1
 3 | .5
 4 | -.5
```

Is it possible to recursively apply a function over all of the table rows?

Comment: How can you have multiple values for `a` in the expected output when you use `where a = 1` in the SQL query?

Comment: maybe a subquery?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, what you need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select b - b0
from
    foo
    cross join
    (select b as b0 from foo where a = 1) s
;
 ?column? 
----------
        0
        1
      0.5
     -0.5
```

Due to the thousands of requests in the comments this is the elegant version:

```
select f1.b - f2.b
from
    foo f1
    cross join
    foo f2
where f2.a = 1
```

Comment: As a matter of pure style, I think this looks a ton better with sane white space and no virtual table: `SELECT f1.b - f2.b FROM foo AS f2 CROSS JOIN foo AS f2 WHERE f2.a = 1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LAG` window function to get the diff between to rows:

```
SELECT b - LAG(b) OVER (ORDER BY a ASC) 
FROM foo;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│   (null) │
│        1 │
│     -0.5 │
│       -1 │
└──────────┘
(4 rows)
```

You can then `SUM` that:

```
SELECT SUM(d) OVER (ORDER BY a ASC)
FROM (
    SELECT a, b - LAG(b) OVER (ORDER BY a ASC)
    FROM foo
) sub(a, d);
┌────────┐
│  sum   │
├────────┤
│ (null) │
│      1 │
│    0.5 │
│   -0.5 │
└────────┘
(4 rows)
```